# How can I print a string while another one keeps printing?

Tags: java, string, animation, loading

I have written some simple code for showing a loading word that keeps moving from side to side. Is it possible to print another string while the previous one keeps printing?

It will look like this:

> ..loading  (The word keeps moving)
>   The main file loaded.
>   The backup file loaded.
>   ....          (these line get printed only once while the loading is still moving)

**I want the code for next lines to be separated with the loading code.**

Loading word code:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        for ( int i=0; i<86; i++ )
        {
            if ( i%17 == 0 )
                System.out.print(".......... \r");
            if ( i%17 == 1 )
                System.out.print(".........L \r");
            if ( i%17 == 2 )
                System.out.print("........Lo \r");
            if ( i%17 == 3 )
                System.out.print(".......Loa \r");
            if ( i%17 == 4 )
                System.out.print("......Load \r");
            if ( i%17 == 5 )
                System.out.print(".....Laodi \r");
            if ( i%17 == 6 )
                System.out.print("....Loadin \r");
            if ( i%17 == 7 )
                System.out.print("...Loading \r");
            if ( i%17 == 8 )
                System.out.print("..Loading. \r");
            if ( i%17 == 9 )
                System.out.print(".Loading.. \r");
            if ( i%17 == 10 )
                System.out.print("Loading... \r");
            if ( i%17 == 11 )
                System.out.print("oading.... \r");
            if ( i%17 == 12 )
                System.out.print("ading..... \r");
            if ( i%17 == 13 )
                System.out.print("ding...... \r");
            if ( i%17 == 14 )
                System.out.print("ing....... \r");
            if ( i%17 == 15 )
                System.out.print("ng........ \r");
            if ( i%17 == 16 )
                System.out.print("g......... \r");


            Thread.sleep(150);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I run the code on windows command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adam is triying to say to you that you must use a thread.

A thread is a process in java, the code is executing in the main thread processor but you can create another one to do another things at the same time, in computer information that kind of things is called concurrency.

I recommend you learn something more about threads in Java, maybe this could help you: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/creating-and-starting-threads.html

For other side, you can put a System.out.println at the end of the conditions to put another string.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this in a separate `Thread`. Unfortunately, you will have to ensure that during `print` your two threads won't have a context switch. Let's assume that you want to print words `loading` and `COUNTING`. Then, without any synchronization, it's very probable that the printed messages will be something like: `loCOUaNTdiINGing`.

Please read about concurrency in Java here: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/index.html

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @farshad You would need to execute multiple thread to print multiple things at the same time, and ensure that they are synchronized. Which means that thread 2 would need to know what character(s) are being printed by thread 1, to avoid duplication (among other things). Apart from the beautiful link Adam has provided, [this is another one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm) that may be of interest to you.

Comment: now I understand how it works but using it looks like an advanced thing to do for a beginner like me, but I'll definitely try to learn more about it. Can come in really handy.